# Count and select sequence of occurrences in vector

Tags: r

I have a vector like this example

```
foo <- c(0,0,0,0,1,3,0,0,0,2,3,1,9,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,2,3,3,0,0,0,0)
```

it means that there are sequences of non-zero numbers (the real data is many vectors length of thousands).

I want to find those sequences that repeat, e.g. more than 2 times only. i.e. the sequence `2,3,1,9` and `2,3,3` above and get the index of these sequence.

Comment: Could you clarify...where/how does `2,3,1,9` repeat in your `foo` vector?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the whole sequence does not repeat but the non-zero numbers occurrence repeat, e.g. `1,3` is the non-zero numbers occur 2 times then zero again.

Answer (score 2):

A way could be:

```
r = rle(foo > 0)
wh = r$lengths > 2 & r$values
mapply(function(a, b) a:(a + b), 
       cumsum(r$lengths)[wh] - r$lengths[wh] + 1, 
       r$lengths[wh] - 1)  #the indices to subset 'foo'
#[[1]]
#[1] 10 11 12 13
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 23 24 25
```

Comment: I did use `rle`, and write manually a function similar to your (in approach) but longer. So I guess there're no simpler way of doing this. I asked because this is just a step in a loop on more than 5000 data involve MCMC, so I tried to reduce the computing  time as much as possible. Thank very much @alexis_laz

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
 which(!!ave(foo, cumsum(c(1,abs(diff(!!foo)))), 
            FUN=function(x) !!x & length(x)>2))
 # [1] 10 11 12 13 23 24 25
```